# Screen density independent font size in html and Webview

Tags: android, html, css, webview, font-size

In Android we have density-independent pixels (dp, sp) for dimensions and font sizes.

What is the alternative in html + phonegapp?

Do we need to make a separate layout for each size class (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi...)?

If the screen density is too high, can the app programmatically "zoom in" the Webpage (WebView), so that the font doesn't look too small?

P.S. viewport-percentage units `vw` and `vh` don't work in an Android webview.

Comment: In CSS, `px` roughly equates to `dp` in Android. The difference is that `px` in CSS will take zoom levels into account, in addition to density.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there a way to tell Android to use px instead of multiplying them by its density factor?

Comment: @edoardotognoni: If you are referring to `px` units in HTML content, I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: I used a workararound and it's working now: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8614303/1617900